# Foreach com 2 condições

Tags: php, sql, query, foreach

Estou tentando colocar duas condições no foreach, porém não estou tendo sucesso.
A ideia é a seguinte: o cliente acessa o site na seguinte URL: /sala/balcao e aparece somente produtos que tenham em seu cadastro no DB o ambiente 'sala' e a categoria 'balcao'.

O código é este que estou utilizando

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ produtos.php?id=$1&cat=$2
```

Página de consulta

```
$ProdAmb=  $_GET['id'];
$ProdCat= $_GET['cat'];

$muda_path = explode('/', $ProdAmb);
$muda_path1 = explode('/', $ProdCat);

foreach($muda_path as $produto_link){
    $ProdID = $produto_link;
    $subcat = $sub;
    $prod_select_categoria = "SELECT * FROM todos_produtos INNER JOIN ambiente_moveis ON ambiente_moveis.nome = todos_produtos.ambiente_prod INNER JOIN categorias_moveis ON categorias_moveis.nome = todos_produtos.categoria_prod WHERE categorias_moveis.link_cat='$subcat' OR ambiente_moveis.link_cat='$ProdID'";
    $query = @mysql_query($prod_select_categoria) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

A tabela 'todos_produtos' contém os dois termos, ambiente e categoria, enquanto a tabela 'ambiente_prod' só tem ambientes e 'categoria_moveis' só tem categorias, ambas tabelas(ambiente e categoria) a estrutura é iguais, mudando somente os dados. Como percebem, o foreach só tem uma condição, mas já tentei com && ou || e nenhuma funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi:

```
    foreach($muda_path as $produto_link){
        $ProdID = $produto_link;
        foreach($muda_path1 as $produto_link1){
            $subcat = $produto_link1;
            $prod_select_categoria = "SELECT * FROM todos_produtos INNER JOIN ambiente_moveis ON ambiente_moveis.nome = todos_produtos.ambiente_prod INNER JOIN categorias_moveis ON categorias_moveis.nome = todos_produtos.categoria_prod WHERE categorias_moveis.link_cat='$subcat' OR ambiente_moveis.link_cat='$ProdID'";
            $query = @mysql_query($prod_select_categoria) or die (mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

Se não resolver o seu problema tente especificar a pergunta e coloque mais dados como o print da estrutura das tabelas + os valores que irão na URL, não consegui entender ao certo que dados serão explodidos e como esse SQL deveria retornar.

Comment: Cara, exatamente. Porém, estou tendo problema com o .htaccess agora. Ele não está conseguindo me retornar a 1ª variável da url, somente a 2ª está me retornando.

Comment: Tente assim:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ produtos.php?id=$1&cat=$2 [L]